# How to store text from a file-list into a variable in c#

Tags: c#, list, file-io

Hi I am new to programming. I would like to read a text file and take the values ( `string`s ) and store each character of the `string` in an `array` individually. I have used a list to take in the vales from the text file. I am finding it difficult to move them into an `array` and then use those values in my program. Please find me a solution if possible. Thanking you in advance.

```
public class file_IO
{
    string[] letters = new string[] //I would like to store it in this variable
    public  void File_Reader()
    {
        string filepath = @"env.txt"; //Variable to hold string
        List<string> file_lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();//returns array of strings into List
        foreach (string line in file_lines)
        {

        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: declare an array first then in your `foreach` loop add to the array

Comment: Do you want to store each line? or the entire file as char array?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Thank you for the reply. How do I move the values from a list to an array ? I am very new to this and do not know the Syntax.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I would like to store each line. As I need to use the values and manipulate them in another class for my main program.

Comment: declare your array `myArray` and then in your `foreach` loop put `myArray.Add(line)`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<char>> linesAsChars = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
                                    .Select(l => l.ToList())
                                    .ToList();
```

This will get a List of List of chars.
`string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so with `ToList` each line in the file is translated to `List<char>`.

Comment: can i ask why you have put `List` twice? i have not seen this before

Comment: Its a `List` of `List<char>`, so every item in this list is a list of chars

Comment: IMO It would be better to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` and then you would have one `List<char>`

Comment: @m.rogalski as i understood, the OP wanted each line separately. if he wanted one list for the entire content then the solution you've provided is enough.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the question is a bit confusing and I don't know if he wants each line character from each line or each character from the whole text :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you!.

```
 public char[] File_Reader()
 {
    string filepath = @"env.txt"; //Variable to hold string
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
    string fileContentInString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    return fileContentInString.ToCharArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to *"store each character of the string in an array individually"* is fairly easy because `string` is in fact an `array` of `char`. You can do this using something like this :

```
char[] letters;

public void File_Reader()
{
    string filepath = @"env.txt";
    letters = File.ReadAllText(filePath).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I have understood your question properly, but from what I have read, I will assume that you want an array of lines (which are `string`s).

In this case, you don't need to do much as the `File.ReadAllLines()` method naturally outputs an array of `string` variables.

Remove the `for` loop and replace

```
List<string> file_lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();//returns array of strings into List
```

with:

```
letters = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
```

In case what you want is actually an array of every char value in your file, I would refer to @m.rogalski's answer and declare an array of char[], for example, declare:

```
char[] fileChars;
```

and then replace the line I mentioned earlier with:

```
fileChars = readAllText(filePath).toCharArray()
```

You will notice that you do *not* need a loop in either of the above situations. Hope I helped.